# How can I link to an external font stylesheet in Communities?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-web-components, lightningstylesheets

I've tried to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/example.css" />`
to my `ThemeLayout.cmp` and listed the font name in my css sheet under the faont-family, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone have anyone advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either upload the external Stylesheet as static Resource and load it via provided Methods as described in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_css_external_platform.htm?search_text=stylesheet) or add the link tag via community head markup as described in the [sfdc help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_head.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)